# jquery: fadeOut().empty().append(...).fadeIn() doesn't work properly only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting the behaviour that I'm seeing. I have a piece of code that aims to fadeOut a container, replace the contents and then fade it back in again when it's done.

I'm using jQuery, so the code looks like this:

```
var transitionToNewContent = function(container, new_content) {
    container.fadeOut().delay(1000).empty().append(new_content).fadeIn();
};


transitionToNewContent($('#id'), "<p>magic</p>");
```

The first time that the link that activates this transition is clicked, the content is replaced instantly, then the fadeout happens, then it fades in again.

Every time after that when the link is clicked, I'm seeing the correct behaviour: fadeout, then fadein with the new content.

Any idea why this is happening?

I've attached a complete html file which shows the behaviour:

I'm fairly new to jquery and I'm trying to do things 'the right way'. Any comments regarding style will be appreciated.

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #main_container {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#loading {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    border: #078600 1px dashed;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: -250px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #cccccc;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    display: none;
}

#main_content {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background: white;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #078600;
    border-left: 1px dotted #078600;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
}

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main_container">
    <div id="sidebar"><h1>Sidebar</h1><p>some text</p></div>
    <div id="loading" style="display: none">&nbps;</div>

    <div id="main_content">
      <h1 id="page_title">Title</h1>
      <div id="page_content"><h2>heading</h2><p>Some testing text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var include = function(src) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>'); 
};

include("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js");
include("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js");

var bootStrapSites = function() {
    var sideBar = $('#sidebar');
    sideBar.delay(1000).fadeIn();
    loadSiteList(sideBar);
};

var transitionToNewContent = function(container, new_content) {
    container.fadeOut().delay(1000).empty().append(new_content).fadeIn();
};

var editSite = function(site) {
    transitionToNewContent($('#page_content'), "<p>This is where the magic will happen</p>");
};

var loadSiteList = function(container) {
//    $.getJSON("/sites/list.json", function(data) {

            var data = $.parseJSON('[{"id": "1", "name": "cool name"}]');
        container.empty(container);
        container.append("<h2>new heading</h2>");
        container.append("<ul id='sitesList'></ul>");

        var sitesList = $('#sitesList');
        $.each(data, function(idx, site) {
            var id = 'show_site_id_' + site._id;
            sitesList.append("<li><a id='" + id + "' href='#'>" + site.name + "</a></li>");
            $('#' + id).click(function() {
                editSite(site);
            });
        });
//  });
};
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   bootStrapSites();
});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, just a made up id value and a valid selector on that id

Comment: no no...you have dollar followed by dot followed by open-paren

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that there are two different types of functions in jQuery -- those that take effect immediately and those that add effects to the effects queue.

Let's take a look at your code:

```
container.fadeOut().delay(1000).empty().append(new_content).fadeIn();
```

- `fadeOut` adds a fade operation to the queue
- `delay` adds a delay to the queue
- `empty` immediately empties the element
- `append` immediately appends the content
- `fadeIn` adds a fade operation to the queue

The functions that add items to the queue return immediately -- they don't wait to complete before taking effect.  This means that all the functions are called at (pretty much) the same time -- they don't wait for the animation functions to complete.

You need to use the callback argument to `fadeOut` instead:

```
container.fadeOut(1000, function(){
    container.empty().append(new_content).fadeIn();
});
```

The function is triggered when the fade operation is complete, so the emptying and appending are delayed until the element is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a callback function to get the effect you are looking for.

```
var transitionToNewContent = function(container, new_content) {
    container.fadeOut(1000, function(){
         $(this).empty().append(new_content).fadeIn();
    });
};
```

This ensures that the container isn't replaced until AFTER the animation is completed.

Comment: This works, is there any way to make sure that the magic number (1000) for fadeOut(1000, ...) is the same as the default value for fadeOut()?

Comment: I believe the default value for all animations is 'fast' = 200, so you could substitute the string 'fast' for 1000 if you want to use the default value. See: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Or you can leave the argument out altogether: `container.fadeOut(fn)` uses the default speed (actually 400ms).

Comment: sorry for bringing this up after so long but for those who come here, .promise().done is another way of doing this with less and easier to understand code. simply call the .promise().done(function(){}) of the object you want to manipulate and put the code you want to run inside the function. it will only run after all the effects on queue for that object have ran.